# How to determine the O/S filename of an installed font?

Tags: c#, windows, fonts

We use a third-party PDF Generator library which requires that you specify the TrueType or Type1 file name when using a font other than the 14 or so that are part of the default PDF standard.

So if I want to use `Bitstream Arrus Bold` I have to know to reference `arrusb.ttf`.

Short of enumerating all of the files in the font folder and creating a disposable PrivateFontCollection to extract the relationships, is there a way to obtain the underlying font name from font information, i.e. given Courier New, Bold, Italic derive `CourBI.ttf`?

I've already looked at the InstalledFontCollection and there's nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind poking around in the registry, take a look at

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts
```

It has pairs like

```
Name = "Arial (TrueType)"
Data = "arial.ttf"
```

You can do this the necessary queries like this:

```
static RegistryKey fontsKey =
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
        @"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts");

static public string GetFontFile(string fontName)
{
    return fontsKey.GetValue(fontName, string.Empty) as string;
}
```

A call to `GetFontFile("Arial (TrueType)")` returns `"arial.ttf"`

You could of course modify the code to append the `(TrueType)` portion to the `fontName`, or to look through everything returned by `fontsKey.GetValueNames()` to find the best match.